# How to implement a custom layer wit multiple outputs in Keras?

Tags: python, output, keras, layer, multipleoutputs

Like stated in the title, I was wondering as to how to have the custom layer returning multiple tensors: out1, out2,...outn?
I tried

```
keras.backend.concatenate([out1, out2], axis = 1)
```

But this does only work for tensors having the same length, and it has to be another solution rather than concatenating two by two tensors every time, is it?

Comment: Have you looked at https://keras.io/models/model/.  Using the keras Model API rather than Sequential, will allow you to define multiple outputs.  If this isn't what you're looking for you probably need to provide more description.

Answer (score 4):

In the `call` method of your layer, where you perform the layer calculations, you can return a list of tensors:

```
def call(self, inputTensor):

    #calculations with inputTensor and the weights you defined in "build"
    #inputTensor may be a single tensor or a list of tensors

    #output can also be a single tensor or a list of tensors
    return [output1,output2,output3]
```

Take care of the output shapes:

```
def compute_output_shape(self,inputShape):

    #calculate shapes from input shape    
    return [shape1,shape2,shape3]
```

The result of using the layer is a list of tensors. 
Naturally, some kinds of keras layers accept lists as inputs, others don't.
You have to manage the outputs properly using a functional API `Model`. You're probably going to have problems using a `Sequential` model while having multiple outputs.

I tested this code on my machine (Keras 2.0.8) and it works perfectly:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
import numpy as np

class Lay(Layer):
    def init(self):
        super(Lay,self).__init__()

    def build(self,inputShape):
        super(Lay,self).build(inputShape)

    def call(self,x):
        return [x[:,:1],x[:,-1:]]

    def compute_output_shape(self,inputShape):
        return [(None,1),(None,1)]


inp = Input((2,))
out = Lay()(inp)
print(type(out))

out = Concatenate()(out)
model = Model(inp,out)
model.summary()

data = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print(model.predict(data))

import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

Comment: when I try this, I get : ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<type 'list'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

Comment: Are you using a `Sequential` model? What is your keras version? What layer you put after this one?

Comment: If you'd share more of the stack trace (not only the message, but the function where this message appears and the file), it might be easier to find the issue.

Comment: I am using keras version 2.1.2. I just worked around it with some Keras.backend.stack() lines